Changed grid origin of raster (EPSG: 3050)
I have an ADF file from this website. Unfortunately, it can't be downloaded easily (https://esdac.jrc.ec.europa.eu/content/european-soil-database-v2-raster-library-1kmx1km). When I read the file in R with terra::rast or drag it into QGIS, there is no CRS defined (probably because there is no .prj-file present). As it says in the documentation, the CRS of the data is EPSG 3050 ( ETRS89 Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area (ETRS_LAEA)), so that the correct CRS can be assigned easily.
I am confused because even when the correct CRS was assigned, the dataset hasn't the correct location (checking with another dataset with same CRS). At website it says: "The grid origin is defined 4.321.000,0 m west of the projection centre point (52N, 10 E), and 3.210.000,0 m south of projection centre point (52N 10 E). The grid extent is such that it covers all EU25 countries. Width : 7.500.000,0 m ; Height : 5.500.00,0 m ; 7500 columns, 5500 rows".

I tried to move the extent of the dataset by subtracting the respective value of the x and y coordinates, this moved the dataset, but not correctly.
Does this position of the grid origin cause the displacement?
How can I work with the data in R (defining new CRS, changing origin, etc.)?


Please run terra::crs() on your existing SpatRaster object (the one your new data does not align with) and add the result as an edit to your question.

If you run the names of the SpatRaster objects to return their metadata, and add those results to your question,  that will help too.
